# High UDP packet loss in Windows 11 but not Ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-11, udp, iperf3

So I'm at a loss (pun intended). I'm seeing packet loss but only on the return leg (showing in iperf but not WinMTR or ping), and only in Windows 11. If I boot up into Ubuntu 22.04, I get minimal loss (acceptable levels). This is heavily impacting download speeds on international routes. I have a 400Mbps fibre line, and getting download speeds of 20 - 50Mbps internationally due to the packet loss.

Below is a summary of what I've tried and found:

- I'm using the latest drivers for the motherboard (Gigabyte B760 GAMING X DDR4) and NIC (Realtek Gaming 2.5GbE Family Controller)
- I've tried 2 other NICs, but unfortunately they were all variations of Realtek boards (but same issue)
- Unlikely to be CPU or other bottleneck with Intel i7-13700KF, 64GB RAM and Mushkin MKNSSDTS1TB-D8 Tempest 1TB SSD
- Replaced cables and tried directly through ONT
- Setup local iPerf server to do testing and same packet loss
- Reset the network adapters on Windows 11
- Turned off security virtualization/hypervisor platform
- Fibre provider has replaced ONT and re-spliced into new PON - no difference (but considering the above, unlikely to be that)
- ISP has been unable to pick up any routing or capacity issues their side
- Tested in "clean boot" mode - no change

Unfortunately I've been unable to test in Safe Mode due to the Realtek drivers not supporting safe mode, but I did a complete clean install and even with the bare minimum there's no change. I can only think that there's a driver issue or some fundamental issue in Windows 11 I'm missing?

Below is an iperf from Windows 11, and then using Ubuntu to the same server, a few minutes apart:

```
iperf3.exe -4 -V -t 30 -O 3 -u -b 400M -l 1440 -R -c *******
iperf 3.15
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-22621 PC 3.4.9-1.x86_64 2023-09-06 11:19 UTC x86_64
Control connection MSS 1460
Time: Wed, 15 Nov 2023 12:39:34 GMT
Connecting to host *******, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host ******* is sending
      Target Bitrate: 400000000
[  5] local 192.168.1.252 port 64574 connected to 196.******* port 5201
Starting Test: protocol: UDP, 1 streams, 1440 byte blocks, omitting 3 seconds, 30 second test, tos 0
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  47.5 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.021 ms  1780/36392 (4.9%)  (omitted)
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  47.6 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.021 ms  91/34724 (0.26%)  (omitted)
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  46.7 MBytes   392 Mbits/sec  0.024 ms  720/34722 (2.1%)  (omitted)
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  47.6 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.062 ms  53/34699 (0.15%)
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  47.1 MBytes   395 Mbits/sec  0.059 ms  438/34748 (1.3%)
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  47.2 MBytes   396 Mbits/sec  0.048 ms  323/34727 (0.93%)
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  47.4 MBytes   398 Mbits/sec  0.056 ms  195/34718 (0.56%)
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  47.6 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.059 ms  69/34722 (0.2%)
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  42.5 MBytes   357 Mbits/sec  0.052 ms  3774/34723 (11%)
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  32.5 MBytes   272 Mbits/sec  0.053 ms  11087/34723 (32%)
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  37.5 MBytes   314 Mbits/sec  0.050 ms  7432/34723 (21%)
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  41.0 MBytes   344 Mbits/sec  0.038 ms  4821/34711 (14%)
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  41.9 MBytes   351 Mbits/sec  0.051 ms  4241/34737 (12%)
[  5]  10.00-11.00  sec  42.4 MBytes   356 Mbits/sec  0.048 ms  3836/34723 (11%)
[  5]  11.00-12.00  sec  42.1 MBytes   353 Mbits/sec  0.037 ms  4072/34725 (12%)
[  5]  12.00-13.00  sec  41.4 MBytes   347 Mbits/sec  0.041 ms  4586/34723 (13%)
[  5]  13.00-14.00  sec  41.2 MBytes   346 Mbits/sec  0.037 ms  4716/34726 (14%)
[  5]  14.00-15.00  sec  43.0 MBytes   360 Mbits/sec  0.041 ms  3440/34722 (9.9%)
[  5]  15.00-16.00  sec  43.1 MBytes   362 Mbits/sec  0.068 ms  3314/34712 (9.5%)
[  5]  16.00-17.00  sec  45.1 MBytes   378 Mbits/sec  0.039 ms  1895/34733 (5.5%)
[  5]  17.00-18.00  sec  45.1 MBytes   379 Mbits/sec  0.026 ms  1865/34730 (5.4%)
[  5]  18.00-19.01  sec  45.8 MBytes   382 Mbits/sec  0.028 ms  1273/34649 (3.7%)
[  5]  19.01-20.00  sec  46.0 MBytes   388 Mbits/sec  0.028 ms  1337/34797 (3.8%)
[  5]  20.00-21.00  sec  45.4 MBytes   381 Mbits/sec  0.025 ms  1670/34729 (4.8%)
[  5]  21.00-22.00  sec  35.6 MBytes   299 Mbits/sec  0.023 ms  8765/34722 (25%)
[  5]  22.00-23.00  sec  39.2 MBytes   329 Mbits/sec  0.024 ms  6169/34722 (18%)
[  5]  23.00-24.00  sec  39.6 MBytes   332 Mbits/sec  0.043 ms  5871/34731 (17%)
[  5]  24.00-25.00  sec  38.7 MBytes   325 Mbits/sec  0.023 ms  6504/34704 (19%)
[  5]  25.00-26.00  sec  39.9 MBytes   335 Mbits/sec  0.046 ms  5654/34737 (16%)
[  5]  26.00-27.00  sec  40.0 MBytes   336 Mbits/sec  0.049 ms  5570/34722 (16%)
[  5]  27.00-28.00  sec  38.3 MBytes   322 Mbits/sec  0.069 ms  6805/34722 (20%)
[  5]  28.00-29.00  sec  40.2 MBytes   337 Mbits/sec  0.045 ms  5445/34722 (16%)
[  5]  29.00-30.00  sec  35.5 MBytes   298 Mbits/sec  0.056 ms  8863/34723 (26%)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Test Complete. Summary Results:
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-30.07  sec  1.40 GBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.000 ms  0/0 (0%)  sender
[SUM]  0.0-30.1 sec  31 datagrams received out-of-order
[  5]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.23 GBytes   352 Mbits/sec  0.056 ms  124083/1041705 (12%)  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Ubuntu:

```
iperf3 -4 -V -t 30 -O 3 -u -b 400M -l 1440 -R -c *******
iperf 3.9
Linux ubuntu 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64
Control connection MSS 1448
Time: Wed, 15 Nov 2023 14:30:09 GMT
Connecting to host *******, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host ********* is sending
      Cookie: *********
      Target Bitrate: 400000000
[  5] local 192.168.1.252 port 44626 connected to 196.******** port 5201
Starting Test: protocol: UDP, 1 streams, 1440 byte blocks, omitting 3 seconds, 30 second test, tos 0
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  47.8 MBytes   401 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  1313/36118 (3.6%)  (omitted)
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.017 ms  0/34722 (0%)  (omitted)
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34723 (0%)  (omitted)
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.015 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34723 (0%)  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  47.6 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.027 ms  46/34694 (0.13%)  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34750 (0%)  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  43.3 MBytes   363 Mbits/sec  0.011 ms  0/31548 (0%)  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  52.0 MBytes   437 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/37896 (0%)  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  47.6 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.016 ms  35/34723 (0.1%)  
[  5]  10.00-11.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  11.00-12.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.010 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  12.00-13.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.015 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  13.00-14.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  14.00-15.00  sec  47.3 MBytes   397 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  244/34723 (0.7%)  
[  5]  15.00-16.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  16.00-17.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34723 (0%)  
[  5]  17.00-18.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34721 (0%)  
[  5]  18.00-19.00  sec  47.6 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.019 ms  44/34723 (0.13%)  
[  5]  19.00-20.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  20.00-21.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.015 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  21.00-22.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.012 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  22.00-23.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  9/34723 (0.026%)  
[  5]  23.00-24.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.013 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  24.00-25.00  sec  47.6 MBytes   399 Mbits/sec  0.026 ms  73/34708 (0.21%)  
[  5]  25.00-26.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.015 ms  0/34737 (0%)  
[  5]  26.00-27.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  27.00-28.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  28.00-29.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
[  5]  29.00-30.00  sec  47.7 MBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.017 ms  0/34722 (0%)  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Test Complete. Summary Results:
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-30.06  sec  1.40 GBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.000 ms  0/1042325 (0%)  sender
[SUM]  0.0-30.1 sec  25 datagrams received out-of-order
[  5]   0.00-30.00  sec  1.40 GBytes   400 Mbits/sec  0.017 ms  451/1041666 (0.043%)  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Any suggestions on the cause and how to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting packet size, MTU (max transmission unit)? See  https://techamor.com/reducing-mtu-on-windows-10/ and https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-change-mtu-on-windows for both Win 10 & 11 help. Note separate settings for Ethernet and other connection types.

Comment: iperf can test different mtu sizes with `-l`. Do you have control of the gateway between your server and the ISP or another device on the network? Many routers can also run iperf, so you could test the connection between you and the router (issues like janky drivers or interface settings should still be present).